# Does setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs affects devices API under 16?

Tags: android, webview

The android API doc of this method setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs says "The default value is true for API level **android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1** and below, and false for API level **android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN** and above." **But this method is added from android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN**, how can it get the default value true for **android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1** and below? If I call this method setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false), I have to set the min sdk version >= 16, or check Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16, if it has a default value true under 16, how can I change it? It's so weird. same problem about setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs.

Comment: Your post is unreadable. It is one big block.